# Inserting a label in the frame

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, gui-construction

I am trying to make a panel that looks like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

I can do:

```
Labeled[Framed[Pane["Content"], ImageSize -> {100, 100}, 
  RoundingRadius -> 5], " text", {{Top, Left}}, Spacings -> {0, -1}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

but the caption is clipped and the frame is missing.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay):

```
Overlay[
    {
    Framed[
        "Content",
        BaselinePosition -> Top -> Baseline,
        ImageSize->{100,100},RoundingRadius->5
    ],
    Row[
        {" ", Style["text",Background->White]},
        BaselinePosition->Center
    ]
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for that `Overlay` function!

Comment: One question. If there is a button in the frame, not just text, it becomes inactive in `Overlay`. Even the help file examples with `Button` and `Manipulate` don't work. What's happening?

Comment: Use `Overlay[{e1, e2}, All, 2]` to have the controls in `e2` be effective.

Comment: Thanks! Great! The examples in the help are misleading and need to be updated then.

Answer (score 7):

```
Experimental`FramedLabeled[
 Pane["Content", ImageSize -> {100, 100}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
 Style["text", Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** This works in version 9, but, as noted by @CarlWoll, it doesn't work in version 11. The code behind is similar to @Carl's answer and we can use it to define a function that works in version 11:

```
framedLabeled = Overlay[{Framed[#, Background -> White, FrameMargins -> {{6, 6}, {6, 12}},
      FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7`], ImageMargins -> 10, RoundingRadius -> 5], 
     Framed[#2, Background -> White, BaseStyle -> {"DialogStyle", Bold, 
        FontColor -> Blend[{Blue, Gray}]}, FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {2, 2}}, 
      FrameStyle -> White, ImageMargins -> {{30, 0}, {0, 0}}]}, All, 1] &;

framedLabeled[Pane["Content", ImageSize -> {100, 100}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
 Style["text", Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately, Experimental`FramedLabeled was a failed experiment, and is no longer present in M11.1.

Comment: Ah, looked so pretty!

Comment: @Carl, thank you. It works in v9. I was about to check if it worked in v11:(

Comment: @CarlWoll Just here to ask why this seemingly successful code is considered a failed experiment ;)

Comment: @Wjx I only said it was a failed experiment because it no longer exists. I don't know anything about why it no longer exists.

Comment: @CarlWoll oh, ;)